# Java Stream - Collections - remove duplicates based on string and presence/absence of local date value

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list of objects with a string (name) and a local date (date of deletion).

I wish to implement uniqueness on these objects based on:

- If two objects have the same name, then I wish the one with no date
  of deletion to have priority.
- If two objects have the same name, and a date of deletion, then I wish the one with the most recent date of deletion to have priority.

Based on the above criteria, I have implemented, what I think is the right solution.

Do you have any pointers as to the correctness of my approach? Do you have any suggestions for improvements?

The class:

```
public class Unique implements Comparable<Unique>
{
    private String name;
    private LocalDate dateOfDeletion;

    public Unique(String name, LocalDate dateOfDeletion) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfDeletion = dateOfDeletion;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfDeletion() {
        return dateOfDeletion;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeletion(LocalDate dateOfDeletion) {
        this.dateOfDeletion = dateOfDeletion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Unique [name=" +name + ", dateOfDeletion="+dateOfDeletion+"],";
    }

    /**
     * order based on name ascending, and date descending
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Unique rhs) {  
        Comparator<Unique> reverseDateComparator = (a, b) -> {
            LocalDate thisDodel = a.getDateOfDeletion() == null ? LocalDate.now().plusDays(1) : a.getDateOfDeletion();
            LocalDate thatDodel = b.getDateOfDeletion() == null ? LocalDate.now().plusDays(1) : b.getDateOfDeletion();
            return thatDodel.compareTo(thisDodel);
        };
        return Comparator.comparing(Unique::getName).thenComparing(reverseDateComparator).compare(this, rhs);
    }
}
```

The Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Unique> uniqueList = Arrays.asList(
                new Unique("a", null) 
                ,new Unique("b", null) 
                ,new Unique("b", LocalDate.of(2016, Month.SEPTEMBER, 20))
                ,new Unique("c", LocalDate.of(2016, Month.SEPTEMBER, 19))
                ,new Unique("c", LocalDate.of(2016, Month.SEPTEMBER, 20))
                );

    System.out.println("list ordered, with duplicates: ");
    uniqueList.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("=================");
    System.out.println("list ordered, duplicates removed: ");
    Comparator<Unique> uniqueComp = (a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo( b.getName() );
    //SOLUTION HERE: since list is already ordered by date desc, it will ignore the records with same name already added to the list  
    TreeSet<Unique> sortedFilterd = uniqueList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<Unique>(uniqueComp)));
    sortedFilterd.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

What I expect to see is the following:

```
list ordered, with duplicates: 
Unique [name=a, dateOfDeletion=null],
Unique [name=b, dateOfDeletion=null],
Unique [name=b, dateOfDeletion=2016-09-20],
Unique [name=c, dateOfDeletion=2016-09-20],
Unique [name=c, dateOfDeletion=2016-09-19],
=================
list ordered, duplicates removed: 
Unique [name=a, dateOfDeletion=null],
Unique [name=b, dateOfDeletion=null],
Unique [name=c, dateOfDeletion=2016-09-20],
```

Here is a link to the working sample: [Link to working sample to the above code](http://ideone.com/wBfDwz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simplification

The code can be simplified using built-in methods from the Comparator API.

> ```
> public int compareTo(Unique rhs) {  
>     Comparator<Unique> reverseDateComparator = (a, b) -> {
>         LocalDate thisDodel = a.getDateOfDeletion() == null ? LocalDate.now().plusDays(1) : a.getDateOfDeletion();
>         LocalDate thatDodel = b.getDateOfDeletion() == null ? LocalDate.now().plusDays(1) : b.getDateOfDeletion();
>         return thatDodel.compareTo(thisDodel);
>     };
>     return Comparator.comparing(Unique::getName).thenComparing(reverseDateComparator).compare(this, rhs);
> }
> ```

The `reverseDateComparator` is primarily used to handle `null` values. However, there are the built-ins comparators [`nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) and [`nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) that exist just for this: they wrap an existing comparator and turn it `null` safe, by considering `null` values either greater or lower than non-`null` values.

As such, you can rewrite this method with:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Unique rhs) {  
    return Comparator.comparing(Unique::getName)
                .thenComparing(Unique::getDateOfDeletion, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .compare(this, rhs);
}
```

This directly passes the method-reference `Unique::getDateOfDeletion` to `thenComparing` and compares the dates by placing `null` values before other values and non-`null` in their reverse natural order (so that the most recent date is sorted before).

Using static imports makes the code a bit cleaner also. With the following imports,

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.Comparator.nullsFirst;
import static java.util.Comparator.reverseOrder;
```

the methods becomes very readable with regard to the initial goal (compare by name, then compare by dates reversed with first no deletion date):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Unique rhs) {  
    return comparing(Unique::getName)
                .thenComparing(Unique::getDateOfDeletion, nullsFirst(reverseOrder()))
                .compare(this, rhs);
}
```

In the same way, the following:

> ```
> Comparator<Unique> uniqueComp = (a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo( b.getName() );
> ```

can be written:

```
Comparator<Unique> uniqueComp = Comparator.comparing(Unique::getName);
```

#### `equals` needs to be overriden

Since your `Unique` class implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), it is strongly recommended to let it override the `equals` method, and have a consistent implementation.

In this case, the `equals` should simply verify the equality of both the names of the date of deletion. To handle `null` values, you can make use of [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-): this method returns `true` when the two given objects are either both `null` or both not-`null` and equal with regard to `equals`.

#### Other comments

- Do you really need setters in your `Unique` class? Consider making that class immutable.
- You have a trailing comma in

  ```
  return "Unique [name=" +name + ", dateOfDeletion="+dateOfDeletion+"],";
  ```
- Does it make sense to allow a `null` name? If not, you can validate that it is always present in the constructor with [`requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-). Also, since the date of deletion might be `null`, a constructor overload without it may be simpler for the client.

Comment: If I could give you more than one upvote, I would. The recommendations are simple, yet nothing short of genius. =0) I couldn't find an example of how to properly implement  Comparator.nullsFirst(). Yours is just what I was looking for.  What I wanted to ask is does stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<Unique>(uniqueComp))); is enough to remove duplicates? Is there a better way to implement this simple solution? Thank you for the recommendations.

Comment: @LucasT Yes it's enough, it will retain uniques with different names. It will always keep the first one in the input list (even if ran in a parallel stream)